# How to change WebView Height?

Tags: java, android

I load in WebView some table from res.
These tables have a different size.
How do I change the size of the height of the WebView content?

I tried:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        myWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

after load content but it doesn't work...

Comment: it's good form to "accept" one of the answers, if it solved your problem. you can choose one by clicking the "tick" beside the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it in layout as

```
android:layout_height="300dp "
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can set size your table layout then you set the your webview height